# How can I make a display:flex container expand horizontally with its wrapped contents?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using css `flexbox` the three main browsers appear to behave entirely differently in certain areas.

In this case I am trying to create a grid of images:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="photo"></div>
     <div class="photo"></div>
     <div class="photo"></div>
     <div class="photo"></div>
     <div class="photo"></div>
     <div class="photo"></div>
</div>


.container {
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-flow : column wrap;
    align-content : flex-start;
    height : 100%;
}
```

In this example I need a container, itself containing several `div` elements set up to flow from top to bottom and wrapping when they reach the bottom.  Ultimately providing me with columns of photos.

However I need the container to expand horizontally to accommodate the wrapped elements:

Here is a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Ku8/3/) to demonstrate.

The behaviour is as follows:

- **IE 11** - Correct, the container stretches horizontally to wrap each column of wrapped elements
- **Firefox** - The container only wraps the first column of elements, with the rest overflow out.
- **Chrome** - The container always stretches to fill the width of its parent, whatever that may be.

In this instance I would like to achieve the behaviour of IE11 in the other two browsers.  Therefore my question is, how can I make a `flexbox` container expand horizontally to match its `column wrap` contents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f7Ku8/4/ as i understood you.

Comment: you have a row layout distribution with a fixed height container ... that does not make sense; test different layouts [here](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto why does that not make sense?  I want the container to be a fixed height but expand horizontally as more columns are added. It is a column layout distribution not a row one.

Comment: @pic0 Thanks but that isn't what i'm after.  Your solution removes flex-box entirely which does indeed make the container expand correctly.  However I need the items to flow from the top to bottom in columns, hence the display:inline-flex or display:flex requirement.

Comment: Do you want it to overflow? It's not clear what's your intention. Do you have an example?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I would like the blue container to expand to fit the column wrapped contents), it does this correctly in IE 11 but does not in Firefox or Chrome.  Try my jsFiddle on all three browsers and you will see the difference.  IE 11 is the behaviour I would like.

Comment: I dont know how IE behaves ... and you shouldn't rely on it since their flex [support is recent](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)... When you set the flex-direction to column you define the Vertical axis as the main axis. In flexbox that means it will fill up the available height and then create a new column.

Comment: @gordyr also notice that firefox and chrome have the same behavior when you use `display:flex` instead of `display:inline-flex`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this issue cannot be solved only with CSS, so I propose you a JQuery solution

container width = position of the last child - position of the container + width of the last child (including margin)

**Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.container').each(function( index ) {
     var lastChild = $(this).children().last();
     var newWidth = lastChild.position().left - $(this).position().left + lastChild.outerWidth(true);
     $(this).width(newWidth);
    })
});
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/qzea320L/

Comment: -1. This might work in simple cases, but if there's *any* potential for the width to change (e.g. due to adding or removing flex items, or changing the height of the flex container) then this is going to break, and if there's no potential for it to change, then why not simply hard-code it in your CSS? Also, this is likely to fail if the flex items have different sizes - you're relying upon the last child being the one whose box extends farthest to the right, but that needn't be true.

Comment: Writing JS instead of CSS doesn't scale. It works only in simplest cases. -1  for jQuery in 2014.

Answer (score 59):

It's curious that most browsers haven't implemented column flex containers correctly, but the support for writing modes is reasonably good.

Therefore, you can use a row flex container with a vertical writing mode. This will swap the block direction with the inline direction, and thus the flex items will flow vertically. Then you only need to restore the horizontal writing mode inside the flex items.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 350px;
  background: blue;
}
.photo {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">1</div>
  <div class="photo">2</div>
  <div class="photo">3</div>
  <div class="photo">4</div>
  <div class="photo">5</div>
  <div class="photo">6</div>
  <div class="photo">7</div>
  <div class="photo">8</div>
  <div class="photo">9</div>
</div>
```

This approach may have its own bugs in edge cases, especially if you mix advanced layout techniques like floats and nested flexboxs. But for most cases it seems to work properly.

Comment: That's a ridiculous hack. Thanks!

Comment: This does not seem to work in Firefox. Especially when in nested flexboxes. I believe this is the "Chrome-specific workaround" that @Mark Amery mentions in his answer.

Comment: thanks
works in Chrome, FF, Edge... (not IE obviously)

Comment: incredible that this bug is still out here late 2019.. Anyway, this work-around works great!

Comment: Brilliant, and still relevant in 2022! I did unspeakable things looking for a solution... had I only known of this earlier...

Comment: Hell yeah !! 2023 still rolling. That thing is incredible! :)

Answer (score 10):

The spec says that what you're doing should work, but it's implemented incorrectly in every major browser besides Internet Explorer / Edge, making multi-line `inline-flex` `column` layouts useless at present for most developers. Here's a [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397) providing an example that is effectively identical to yours, and noting that it renders incorrectly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

The argument from spec is more complicated than I'm able to understand, but the key point is that [Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1) spec defines the *intrinsic* cross-size of a flex container (that is, the intrinsic height of a `flex-direction: row` flex container or the intrinsic width of a `flex-direction: column` flex container) in the section [Flex Container Intrinsic Cross Size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#intrinsic-cross-sizes). There, it is stated:

> For a [multi-line](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#multi-line) [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container), the [min-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content)/[max-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#max-content) [cross size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-size) is the sum of the flex line cross sizes

That is, the intrinsic width of a `flex-direction: column` flex container should be the sum of the widths of its columns, as you'd expect. (There is more complexity than this, and I don't understand it all, but I believe the above to be broadly true.) However, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all calculate this width incorrectly; setting `width: min-content` or `width: max-content` on a `column wrap` `flex` box in Chrome, you can clearly see that the width is set to the width of the widest single element.

A [silly Chrome-specific workaround](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397#c21) exists, but is probably best avoided. Until the bug is fixed, this part of the Flexbox model simply doesn't work as designed and there's no clean solution available.

Answer (score -1):

You have a column layout distribution with a fixed height container.

When you set the flex-direction to column you define the Vertical axis as the main axis.

In flexbox that means it will fill up the available height and then create a new column.

In this **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cegor/2/edit)** I use javascript to change the container's height and, because of that, you will see the child items move.

PS: you shouldn't rely on IE behavior since their flex support is recent.

Comment: I understand all of this but it doesn't really answer my question I am afraid.  I am simply looking for a way to make the flex-box container element automatically expand horizontally to match its contents.  If this is not possible then so be it.  But it is disappointing since all three browsers behave completely differently in this regard. PS I am not relying on IE's behaviour, that is why I am asking this question.  Regardless, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible approach:

```
.container {
  column-count: 2; /*or whatever */
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

You may also need to adjust `margin-top` of `.container > div:first-child` if they don't align to the top.

Comment: Don't copy/paste the same answer all over, post at one place and then vote to close on the other ... [Is it ok to copy/paste myself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317609/is-it-ok-to-copy-paste-myself)

Comment: Furthermore, this answer doesn't provide a solution to the asked question, since it will create a different flow than what is asked for.

Comment: I'll try to take your rebukes and downvotes to heart. In my defense, I had just spent too much time looking at SO pages about flex, when what I needed was column-count, and I was trying to help others to have a better experience.