# Make flex container with columns shrink-to-fit

Tags: css, flexbox, shrink

Assume we have a container, whose children have to fill it in columns. The container is limited in height and has to be as wide/narrow as need for all the descendants to fit. It should look like this:

[image]

To make this I try `flexbox`. The question is: is it possible to make it shrink-to-fit?

- `float:left`: in Chrome doesn't do the trick at all, in Firefox the container has the width of only one column - [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/chn2opgk/3/)
- `position:absolute`: it doesn't contribute to normal flow, so discard this.

For now I narrow down the browser range to Chrome and FF.

The HTML:

```
<div class="flexcontainer wrap column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.flexcontainer{
    display: flex;              /* make it a flexbox */
    flex-flow: column wrap;     /* make it a column container, and fill them one after another */

    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    float: left;                /* shrink-to-fit */

    max-height: 450px;          /* limit the height */
    min-height: 300px;
}
.flexcontainer > div {
    height: 100px;            
    margin: 3px;
    width: 100px;               /* set the width of descendants */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a maximum number of items?

Comment: Also, can your page extend beyond the normal width and height of the viewport?

Comment: Any update on how you solved this or is jquery the only way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a display:flex container expand horizontally with its wrapped contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408539/how-can-i-make-a-displayflex-container-expand-horizontally-with-its-wrapped-con)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.flexcontainer').each(function( index ) {
     var parentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
     var childHeight = $(this).children().outerHeight();
     var childCount = $(this).children().length;
     var cols = Math.ceil(childHeight*childCount/parentHeight);

     var childWidth = $(this).children().outerWidth();
     var padding = 15;
     $(this).width(childWidth*cols+padding);
    })
});
```