# Flex container calculating one column, when there are multiple columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an `li` of 15 items displaying as `flex-direction: column` (it's applied to the parent (`ul`)). I then have a `div` wrapping the `ul` with the property of `justify-content: center`.

The problem is, the `div` calculates the `ul` as if it's only one column, even though I have multiple columns. So the width of the is `ul` `200px` when it should be `800px`. Therefore, when I add the property of `justify-content: center` (or `flex-end`) to the `div`, it centers the `ul` as if it's only `200px`, so it doesn't center properly.

How can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```css
div {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
li {
  outline: 1px solid;
  background-color: greenYellow;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obstacle you have encountered is a fundamental deficiency in flex layout:

> **A flex container in column-direction will not expand along with its wrapping items.**

This problem can be illustrated by wrapping a border around the `ul`:

[image]

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1w4uvj8/1/)

You'll notice that the container keeps a fixed width, able to accommodate a single column. Wrapping columns simply overflow it. This problem has been  documented here: *[When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)*

**As a solution** you can:

- switch to `flex-direction: row`, which has no problem containing wrapping items ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y1w4uvj8/2/))
- use something other than `display: flex`, such as `display: inline-block`
- Use Javascript/jQuery. Here's one possible fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231447/3597276