# Make flex items wrap in a column-direction container

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap, css-grid

So, to wrap elements in a flex div using a row layout all I have to do is this:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  /* I want to change this to column */
  flex-wrap: wrap;      /* wrap doesn't seem to work on column, only row */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>these</p>
  <p>will</p>
  <p>wrap</p>
</div>
```

This works for my rows, but I want to make it work for my columns as well.

I tried just changing `flex-direction` to `column`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know how to get this functionality?

Comment: Row works as is, and when the items reach the width of the viewport/container it wraps, but for column, and since the viewport does not have a height (default is `auto`), it will just continue to grow, so for it to actually wrap, it needs a set height.

Comment: Ah, you are very wise. I had the height set on my parent element, but not directly on my flex-box. I just set it to inherit and voila! It works! Thanks a lot! Does that mean that the viewport only keeps track of width and not height?

Comment: Yes, a page's normal flow is downwards, hence it will simply start scroll when content gets to big, with sideways it does not

Comment: very nice. However, now my flex-box div is not containing the new columns that are made when my content wraps. the flex-box div only has a width which contains the first column. Is there any way to make my flex-box expand to contain its contents?

Comment: May I link to this post, it has a lot about all this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width

Comment: Also, generally, giving the flex items `flex: 1` will make them fill the remaining space, either horizontally for flex row, or vertical for flex column

Comment: That is a useful link. I found this post as well indicating that the column flex model is broken in that container width will not expand to contain wrapped children. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408539/how-can-i-make-a-displayflex-container-expand-horizontally-with-its-wrapped-con I will try setting the flex property to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: setting `flex:1` did the trick! Thank you! You saved me a lot of time! If you post an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: There is a lot answers already covering this, and the one given by Michael_B's is more _correct_, so go for that and the `flex: 1` is on me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block-level elements, by default, take up the full width of their containing block. This, in effect, resolves to `width: 100%`, which sets a break in the flow of content in the horizontal direction.

So, flex items can wrap by default in a row-direction container.

Nothing in HTML or CSS, however, sets a default height on block-level elements. Heights are content-driven (`height: auto`).

This means that elements will flow vertically without having any reason to break.

(I guess somewhere along the line of evolution, possibly on the basis of usability studies, it was decided that it would be okay for web applications to expand vertically, but not horizontally.)

That's why flexbox doesn't automatically wrap items in column direction. It requires an author-defined height to serve as a breaking point.

---

Often times, however, a layout's height is dynamic so a specific height cannot be set. That makes flexbox unusable for wrapping items in column direction. A great alternative is CSS [Grid Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), which doesn't require a height setting on the container:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

p:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: aqua;
}

p:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

p:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ONE</p>
  <p>TWO</p>
  <p>THREE</p>
  <p>FOUR</p>
  <p>FIVE</p>
  <p>SIX</p>
  <p>SEVEN</p>
  <p>EIGHT</p>
  <p>NINE</p>
</div>
```

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. I'm currently using `writing-mode:vertical-lr` and `flex-direction:row` to get past a little bug where the flexbox doesn't grow to fit wrapped content, and I set a height on my flexbox to get the content to wrap.

Comment: CSS Grid is no use for this column layout problem either because it ends up aligning all items to same height on each column which looks bad... need to be able to layout columns AND have each item in each column be directly underneath each other, and NOT lined up in a grid structure with gaps all over the place caused by "not the same height" items in grid.