# Inside flex there are 2 divs (left and right), with nested flex divs. Right now the right div is over the left one. How to make a gap between them?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my current code:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Interests</p>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column; height: 240px">
      <div>some</div>
      <div>data here</div>
      <div>test message</div>
      <div>some</div>
      <div>data here</div>
      <div>test message</div>
      <div>some</div>
      <div>data here</div>
      <div>test message</div>
      <div>some</div>
      <div>data here</div>
      <div>test message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p class="mb-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Price</p>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <div>right data 1</div>
        <div>right data 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="mb-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Duration</p>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <div>right data 3</div>
        <div>right data 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the current look:
[image]

How can I move "Price + Duration" block to the right without specifying width, because "Interests" may have different amount of columns?

Comment: Yes. Just did not convert Headers to raw css :) For me the answer with raw css or bootstrap could be ok, I can convert css back to bootstrap. Just can not find out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Why not use the [traditional Bootstrap way](https://jsfiddle.net/dL07ojcp/6/) to do so ?

Comment: @Tommy I was able to get your version, but try to remove the last 2 divs `data here` and `test message` and you will see that there is free space that I do not need.

Comment: How about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wj10uzrg/2/) using `col-auto` on the first column ?

Comment: Nope. `col-auto` works ok just with one column (10 items), but in my case could be any amount of items, so I need a solution which can make the parent div wider or narrower depending on the amount of columns, without overlapping left and right blocks ([Interests] and [Price + Duration])

Comment: The problem is that `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column;` does not change the `div`'s width, which causes the `col-auto` class not to scale properly. Interesting behavior. I could not find a solution yet.

Comment: Also have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width).

Comment: @Tommy thanks for the link that helped me to find solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209546/4992248 . You can create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408539/how-can-i-make-a-displayflex-container-expand-horizontally-with-its-wrapped-con/41209546#41209546):

```css
.interests-by-columns {
    display: inline-flex;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 220px;
}

.interest-item {
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="display: flex">
    <div>
        <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Interests</p>
        <div class="interests-by-columns">
            <div class="interest-item">some</div>
            <div class="interest-item">data here</div>
            <div class="interest-item">test message</div>
            <div class="interest-item">some</div>
            <div class="interest-item">data here</div>
            <div class="interest-item">test message</div>
            <div class="interest-item">some</div>
            <div class="interest-item">data here</div>
            <div class="interest-item">test message</div>
            <div class="interest-item">some</div>
            <div class="interest-item">data here</div>
            <div class="interest-item">test message</div>
            <div class="interest-item">some</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ml-5 mr-2" style="width: 180px">
        <div>
            <p class="mb-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Price</p>
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
            <div>right data 1</div>
            <div>right data 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p class="mb-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Duration</p>
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
            <div>right data 3</div>
            <div>right data 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```